# Sympy - Is there a way to apply the isprime() function to a Pandas column without doing it row by row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sympy

E.g. something like `df['A_isPrime'] = sympy.isprime(df['A'])` to return if the numbers in column A are prime or not?

Comment: If `df` is a pandas dataframe, then `df['A']` is a pandas Series.  `df['A'].values` is a 1d numpy array.  I haven't read `isprime` docs, but I expect it just works with one integer.  So yes, you will have to iterate in some way or other to apply it to all elements of that array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your dataframe is something like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(1, 20)})
```

Then you could apply a function (any function, for example `sympy.isprime`) to a column through the `apply` method:

```
df['A_isPrime'] = df['A'].apply(sympy.isprime)
```

and get:

```
     A  A_prime
0    1    False
1    2     True
2    3     True
3    4    False
4    5     True
5    6    False
6    7     True
7    8    False
8    9    False
9   10    False
10  11     True
11  12    False
12  13     True
13  14    False
14  15    False
15  16    False
16  17     True
17  18    False
18  19     True
```

Comment: Isn'r `apply` doing it row-by-row?  Using the `apply` `raw` mode might improve speed.  `isprime` may be slow enough that the exact iteration mechanism may not matter.

Comment: Depends what you mean by row-by-row. Ultimately any implementation will have to loop over the rows somehow. It won't be possible to get any speed benefit from vectorisation while using the `isprime` function. If the number of rows is large and the integers are bounded by N then precomputing all primes less than N might be faster. SymPy has other functions for doing that e.g. `set(primerange(10000))`.

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful. The 'row-by-row' implementation I was thinking of would be explicitly going through the individual rows through a loop so the apply solution works for me as it is much cleaner code. I'm new to coding/Python so this is all stuff that is new to me.